# Can't add component to a prefab in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add a Rigid body to a prefab. However the 'Add component' button isn't working (The video makes it look like I'm clicking above the button, but that's just the video capture app acting up).

https://youtu.be/pcjUj55Pd8w

Comment: Well this is weird, I am not sure what I think about this, you say you can't add component your video showing you cant add component doesnt show you clicking add component, but you say the video capture software is messing up? Why would only your moouse be messed up in the video capturing software and nothing else?

Comment: I'm with Eddge. It does not look to me like you tried to add a component at all, just went into Prefab Mode and hovered your mouse near (but not on) the Add Component button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird. I would just create an entirely new prefab or restart unity/your PC. Unity has a habit of acting up in similar ways for me.

Comment: It started working after the 2nd unity restart. I guess being new to this platform I just need to be aware that it's finicky and not panic.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be adding it to Hierarchy and like previously do the apply on the Inspector.

The apply button does not exist anymore but on the same place there is the option that overrides all prefabs, doing the same thing.